# Key Binding not Working

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I have the following code as shown below for my .emacs file. For some reason the keybinding is not working nor are the extensions for deft I am pretty sure. Does anybody know why this is?

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(package-initialize)

(setq deft-extensions '("txt" "tex" "org"))

(setq deft-recursive t)
(global-set-key [f8] 'deft)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(custom-enabled-themes '(tsdh-dark))
 '(package-selected-packages '(deft ##)))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Comment: Where do you `(require 'deft)`?

Comment: @nega: Please consider turning your comment into an answer. (Comments can be deleted at any time. Q&A need to stand on their own.)

Comment: Assuming they *have* installed `deft` as a package (as the config suggests) and also assuming that deft provides an autoload cookie for the `deft` command, it wouldn't be necessary for `(require 'deft)`.

Comment: Yes, confirming that `deft` would be autoloaded when `package-initialize` was called.  The question then is "is the deft package *actually* installed?"